# How Can I Run the WPF application at Windows startup without using any code

Tags: c#, wpf, startup

I have created one WPF application and i converted that application into exe. Now i want to run the application while windows startup.Is there any way to startup my app without writing any new code in my WPF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to do that as part of your installation script, not as part of your application (consider asking the user for consent).

See here for an example: [Set that a program has to run at startup from an installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092477/set-that-a-program-has-to-run-at-startup-from-an-installer)

So technically, the answer to your question is: yes, you can do that without any code changes to your application.

Comment: its working...Without using installer code any other Possible ways? @Patrich kulg

Comment: i tried without installer.I have only exe now just i paste my exe shortcut inside startup .Now it also working...while i startup the window ,automatically my app also started to execute

Comment: that will only work on your machine and requires manual work. I assumed you want a solution that you can apply to any machine where your app is installed.