# Icon not shown on desktop shortcut with Visual Studio setup project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, setup-project

In the file system area of my visual Studio 2015 setup project, I have created a shortcut that points to a .BAT file that has been added to the project in the application directory.  I edited the properties for the shortcut and specified an Icon that is in the application directory as well.

When I build and run the install, the desktop shortcut has a default windows icon instead of the one I selected.   If I check the properties, the button to select a new icon is disabled.  That led me to the discussion here:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b57f1d84-9b0c-4c29-b140-0555f92ffed8/target-field-disabled-in-shortcut-created-in-deployment-project?forum=vssetup

I ran the setup with the parameter to disable the advertised shortcuts and the button to select a new icon is now enabled and I can manually select the icon, however, on install, the default icon is still displayed.

If I go in to properties for the created icon and attempt to manually set the icon, I get the following message: "The file %SystemRoot%\Installer{D0981E95-0351-4CA4-9315372F337F244}_8FA4153355CE75C35E4132.exe contains no icons.  Choose an icon from the list or specify a different file."

The icon I'm referencing is a 256x256 icon file.

Does anyone have any idea why I can't get the icon I select for the shortcut to "stick"?

Comment: Is the icon present in the installed directory?

Comment: Maybe the same as this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39784457/winform-app-name-shown-as-alphanumeric-on-startup-tab-in-task-manager-in-window/40408122#40408122

Answer (score 0):

If you right click your setup project and select `View File System` you should see a list of folders on `File system on Target Machine`.

Select the User's Desktop folder and you should see a shortcut File.  If you select the properties for that file `F4` there is a property for Icon that you can set.