# How to extract .msi features from command line?

Tags: windows, windows-installer

I have an .msi that contains some development files (gstreamer development files) and I want to extract some features from .msi to some folder without installing from command line.

I know how to install some features using ADDLOCAL property of msiexec:

```
msiexec /i gstreamer.msi /qb TARGETDIR=some\folder ADDLOCAL=_gstreamer_1.0_system,_gstreamer_1.0_libav
```

But when I'm trying to extract files without installing using administrative installation, it seems ADDLOCAL property doesn't work and it extract all files in package:

```
msiexec /a gstreamer.msi /qb TARGETDIR=some\folder ADDLOCAL=_gstreamer_1.0_system,_gstreamer_1.0_libav
```

Does somebody know how to extract only selected features from .msi without installing it into system?

Comment: Added a sample VBScript showing how you can set `Feature Level` programmatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ***Short Answer***: Make a transform, set **`Feature Table => Level Column to 0`** for features you want to exclude from file extract. Run administrative installation as follows:
>
> ```
> msiexec.exe /a MySetup.msi TRANSFORMS=MyTransform.mst TARGETDIR=C:\MyExtractPath\
> ```

---

***Transform***: There might be other ways that I can't think of at the moment, but one way you can try is to make a transform that you apply to the administrative installation. Depending on the number of features in the MSI this could be a lot of work, or it might not be much work at all (if there are few features you want to exclude).

***Feature Level***: There is a peculiarity in an MSI whereby a [**feature**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/feature-table) that has its [**Feature level**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/feature-table#Level) set to **`0`** will not be extracted during an administrative installation. This seems like a bug to me (it is by design though), but you can use it to achieve what you want here - I think - but it isn't exactly pretty.

1. ***Transform***: Make a transform that sets the Level column in the Feature table to 0 for all the features you do not want to extract.
2. ***msiexec.exe***: Apply the transform to the MSI via the command line as follows:

   ```
   msiexec.exe /a MySetup.msi TRANSFORMS=MyTransform.mst TARGETDIR=C:\MyExtractPath\
   ```

---

***Tools***: You need a tool to help you make this transform. You probably have this already, but for others: I recommend [Orca.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/orca-exe) - Microsoft's own SDK tool. However, there are a number of tools you can use that are free. The majority (I think) are described here: [How can I compare the content of two (or more) MSI files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48482545/how-can-i-compare-the-content-of-two-or-more-msi-files) (scroll down to the list towards bottom - `dark.exe` is a decompiler and not an MSI viewer - the link describes comparing MSI files, not changing them).

**Orca.exe** will already be on disk (most likely) if you have **Visual Studio** installed. Try searching for **`Orca-x86_en-us.msi`** - under **`Program Files (x86)`**. Just install it and find Orca in the start menu (or search for it).

---

***Advanced***: There is a **VBScript** (`widiffdb.vbs`) linked in the above "compare MSI" answer. It allows comparison of two MSI files. There is another VBScript which allows you to update an MSI via SQL statements. See here: [WiRunSQL.vbs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372865(v=vs.85).aspx). These scripts you can find on disk if you have the SDK installed, or you can find them on [github.com](https://www.github.com). See sample use of the script towards the bottom in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51092246/create-msi-and-enforce-all-users-with-visual-studio/51103086#51103086). ***Try this if you have a massive amount of Feature levels to set to 0***. Obviously set all features to 0 and then manually switch on the ones you need by setting them back to normal (1 or higher - depends on the MSI).

***Mockup***: Sample VBScript code to set all **`Feature levels`** to **`0`**:

> ***Note!*** Do not run this on your main source MSI file. ***Make a copy!***
>
> **No error handling in this script**. [To generate a transform see sample here](https://github.com/pauldotknopf/WindowsSDK7-Samples/blob/master/sysmgmt/msi/scripts/WiGenXfm.vbs) (generate transform based on diff between original and modified MSI file).

```vb
Const msiOpenDatabaseModeTransact = 1
Const msiViewModifyReplace = 4

Set installer = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")
Set database = installer.OpenDatabase("Test.msi", msiOpenDatabaseModeTransact)

' Allow user to cancel operation
If MsgBox ("Only run this on a COPY of your MSI!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Continue?", vbYesNo + vbInformation, "Warning!") = vbNo Then
   MsgBox "Update Aborted.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Aborted" 
   WScript.Quit(0)
End If

sql = "SELECT * FROM `Feature`"
Set view = database.OpenView(sql)
view.Execute()

Do
   Set record = view.Fetch()
   If record Is Nothing Then Exit Do
   record.IntegerData(6) = 0
   view.Modify msiViewModifyReplace, record
Loop

view.Close()
database.Commit()

MsgBox "Update Complete.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Completed"
```