# Visual studio project installer, startup folder, filename

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2017, installation, visual-studio-setup-proje

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Installer Projects to make an installer for my application.

I have made a shortcut to the primary output in the users startup folder.
It is working, and the application is started when the user logs in.

However when i look in the task manager it looks like this:

[image: task manager]

can i change the name of that exe file ?

also it points to : 
C:\Windows\Installer{F668DB0C-7317-442D-911D-4EAFB32EEA74}
and not the application folder under "C:\Program Files (x86)\"

bit confused about this, any ideas ?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39784457/winform-app-name-shown-as-alphanumeric-on-startup-tab-in-task-manager-in-window

Comment: More than 7 years ago, Microsoft recommends people move away from it, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckh/2011/03/17/visual-studio-setup-projects-vdproj-will-not-ship-with-future-versions-of-vs/ WiX, though has a sharper learning curve, does work much better.